# C++ A* Pathfinding help find issue ? (Infinite Loop)

Tags: c++

I am trying to debug my pathfinding algorithm I made adjustments to it to try and make it quicker and I broke it again for the 5th time, could someone help me debug it?

It appears to get stuck in an infinite loop, I was using the tutorials [here](http://web.mit.edu/eranki/www/tutorials/search/).

Psuedocode I got from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm).

I'm sorry I cannot show much to process as it goes, I was just hoping people could decipher the logic.

My heuristic gets CWaypoints using a general square root 1 , 1.4 for adjacent and diagonals and also has a terrain cost, 999 for impassible and 0 for normal, 4 for water, the specific reasons I want to not make a bool to hold whether a waypoint is passible is due to the fact that certain objects in the game can travel anywhere and they will not take the 999 cost.

The grid is also connected top to bottom.

```
void fRetracesteps(vector<CWaypoint*> &Current)
{
    ofstream ostMoveFile;
    ostMoveFile.open("move.txt");
    CWaypoint* path = Current[0];
    int MAX_MOVES = 0;

    while (path != 0 && MAX_MOVES <= 200)
    {
        cout << path->ret_posX() << ":" << path->ret_posY() << endl;
        ostMoveFile << path->ret_posX() << " " << path->ret_posY() << "\n";
        path = path->m_parent;
        MAX_MOVES++;
    }
    ostMoveFile.close();
}





void pf_foreach(int current_x, int current_y, int top_x, int top_y, int dest_x, int dest_y, vector<vector<CWaypoint*>> &myvec, deque<CWaypoint*>&OPEN, deque<CWaypoint*>&CLOSED, vector<CWaypoint*> &Current, CWaypoint &pState )
{

    current_x = Current[0]->ret_posX();
    current_y = Current[0]->ret_posY();
    // for each
    const int dx[8] = { 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1 };
    const int dy[8] = { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1 };
    const float manhattan[8] = { 1.0f, 1.41f, 1.0f, 1.41f, 1.0f, 1.41f, 1.0f, 1.41f };
    //cout << pos_x << " : " << pos_y << endl;

    

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        int nx = current_x + dx[i];
        int ny = current_y + dy[i];
        

        if (nx == dest_x && ny == dest_y)
        {
            cout << "goal found" << endl;
            continue;
        }

        if (nx > top_x - 1)
        {
            nx = 0;
        }
        if (nx < 0)
        {
            nx = top_x - 1;
        }
        if (ny > top_y - 1)
        {
            ny = 0;
        }
        if (ny < 0)
        {
            ny = top_y - 1;
        }

        // if its already on closed list dont do
        
            
        pState.m_parent = myvec[current_x][current_y];
        cout << "X:" << nx << ":Y:" << ny << " ";
        cout << "Parent: " << current_x << ":" << current_y << endl;;
        
        pState = CWaypoint(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        pState.set_posX(nx);
        pState.set_posY(ny);
        pState.set_waypoint_coords(myvec[nx][ny]->GetX(), myvec[nx][ny]->GetY(), myvec[nx][ny]->GetZ());
        pState.mAccumulatedCost = myvec[nx][ny]->mAccumulatedCost;
        pState.mHeuristic_Manhattan = manhattan[i];
        pState.mvalue_f = pState.mHeuristic_Manhattan + pState.mAccumulatedCost + pState.ret_terraincost();
        

        bool check = false;
        // If its not on open list, add to open list
        for (auto ceg = OPEN.begin(); ceg != OPEN.end(); ++ceg)
        {
            if ((*ceg)->ret_posX() != nx && (*ceg)->ret_posY() != ny)
            {
                if ((*ceg)->ret_f_cost() < pState.ret_f_cost())
                {
                 check = true;
                }
            }
        }
        bool check2 = false;
        for (auto ceg = CLOSED.begin(); ceg != CLOSED.end(); ++ceg)
        {
            if ((*ceg)->ret_posX() != nx && (*ceg)->ret_posY() != ny)
            {
                if ((*ceg)->ret_f_cost() < pState.ret_f_cost())
                {
                 check2 = true;
                }
            }
        }
        
        if (check)
        {
            continue;
            check = false;
        }
        if (check2)
        {
            continue;
            check2 = false;
        }
        
        cout<<":"<< pState.m_parent << endl;
        //cout << "Accumu: " << pState->mAccumulatedCost << endl;
        //cout << "Accumu: " << pState->mHeuristic_Manhattan << endl;
        OPEN.push_front(new CWaypoint(pState));
        pState.resetall();
        
        //cout << "Pushing " << &myvec[nx][ny] << endl;

        

        

        
    }
}

bool cmp(CWaypoint *lhs, CWaypoint *rhs)
{
    return lhs->ret_f_cost() < rhs->ret_f_cost();
}

void pathfinder(vector<vector<CWaypoint*>> &myvec, int start_x, int start_y , int dest_x, int dest_y, EntityUnit Unit, int top_x , int top_y)
{
    // Pseudocode
    // initialize the open list
    // initialize the closed list
    deque<CWaypoint*>OPEN;
    deque<CWaypoint*>CLOSED;
    vector<CWaypoint*> Current;
    CWaypoint pState(myvec[start_x][start_y]->GetX(), myvec[start_x][start_y]->GetY(), myvec[start_x][start_y]->GetZ(), start_x, start_y);
    pState.set_cost(0);
    // push the initial state on the open list
    // current node in open list with lowest F Cost
    OPEN.push_back(new CWaypoint(pState));
    cout << "pushing first node onto open list" << endl;

    // Values Value_G = Manhattan Distance = mHeuristic_Manhattan
    // Value: Value_MC = Movement Cost Heuristic  = mNodeCost
    // Value: Value_F = H + MC = m_valuef
    string unittype = to_string(Unit.UDReturnUnitType()); // get unit type so we can know what kind of terrain it likes


    int current_x = start_x;
    int current_y = start_y;
    bool reached_target = false;

    // look for lowest cost on open list

    float last_f_cost = 999;
    float current_f_cost = 0;

    current_f_cost = 1;


    // While open list is not empty
    int max_range = 0;
    bool dest_found = false;
    while (OPEN.empty()!= true && dest_found == false)
    {
        // find the node with the least f on the open list and call it p
        pState = *OPEN[0];
        Current.push_back(new CWaypoint(pState));
        std::sort(OPEN.begin(), OPEN.end(), cmp);
        // pop p off the open list
        OPEN.pop_front();
    
        if (Current[0]->ret_posX() == dest_x && Current[0]->ret_posY() == dest_y)
        {
            cout << "dest found" << endl;
            dest_found = true;
            fRetracesteps(Current);
            continue;
        
        }
        pf_foreach(pState.ret_posX(), pState.ret_posY(), top_x, top_y, dest_x, dest_y, myvec, OPEN, CLOSED, Current, pState);
        Current.clear();
        CLOSED.push_back(new CWaypoint(pState));
        max_range++;
    }

    
}
```

Waypoint Class

```
class CWaypoint
{

    int pos_x = 0; // position in grid
    int pos_y = 0;
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    float z = 0;

    float terrainCost = 0; // this cost is determined by terrain type, which is used in the A* pathfinding
    float f_cost = 0;

    float influence = 0;
    string current_owner = "NULL";
    string waypointname = "WP";
    string wp_terraintype = "NULL";
    vector <CWaypoint *> connected_nodes;


    // LAND
    // WATER
    // MOUNTAIN
    // NULL - not passible
    // AIR
    // NUKE
    
public:
    // Values for pathfinder
    int cubesnumber;
    float mAccumulatedCost = 0;
    float mHeuristic_Manhattan = 0;
    float mvalue_f = 0;
    CWaypoint* m_parent;
    // ---------------------------------
    CWaypoint(float _x, float _y, float _z, int _pos_x, int _pos_y)
    {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        z = _z;
        pos_x = _pos_x;
        pos_y = _pos_y;
        stringstream ss;
        ss << "WP " << x << ":" << y << ":" << z;
        waypointname = ss.str();
    }

    ~CWaypoint()
    {
        
    };


    void set_waypoint_coords(float _x, float _y, float _z)
    {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        z = _z;
    }

    float ret_terraincost() const
    {
        return terrainCost;
    }

    void set_cost(float cost)
    {
        this->terrainCost = cost;
    }

    float ret_f_cost() const
    {
        return f_cost;
    }

    void set_f_cost(float cost)
    {
        f_cost = cost;
    }

    void find_adjacent_nodes(vector<vector< CWaypoint*>> TheWaypoints, int top_x, int top_y)
    {
        // function adds the adjacent nodes to it and top_x and top_y is the maximum boundary of the grid so if it goes over, the node will connect to the bottom
        // node beneath it goes over the top, or if over the right, goes back to the left, effectively wrapping the nodes around the sphere for the pathfinding
        const int dx[8] = { 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1 };
        const int dy[8] = { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1 };
        //const float cost[8] = { 1.0f, 1.41f, 1.0f, 1.41f, 1.0f, 1.41f, 1.0f, 1.41f }; - important but we dont do the calculation here
        //cout << pos_x << " : " << pos_y << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
    
            int nx = pos_x + dx[i];
            int ny = pos_y + dy[i];
    
        
            // wrapper 
            if (nx > top_x -1)
            {
                nx = 0;
            }
            if (nx < 0)
            {
                nx = top_x -1;
            }
            if (ny > top_y -1)
            {
                ny = 0;
            }
            if (ny < 0)
            {
                ny = top_y -1;
            }
        
            //cout << nx << " : " << ny << endl;
            connected_nodes.push_back(TheWaypoints[nx][ny]);
        }
        //cout << "_________" << endl;
    }

    int ret_posX() const
    {
        return pos_x;
    }

    void set_posX(int pos_x)
    {
        this->pos_x = pos_x;
    }

    int ret_posY() const
    {
        return pos_y;
    }

    void set_posY(int pos_y)
    {
        this->pos_y = pos_y;
    }

    float GetX() const
    {
        return x;
    }

    float GetY() const
    {
        return y;
    }

    float GetZ() const
    {
        return z;
    }

    string returnterraintype()
    {
        return wp_terraintype;
    }

    void setterraintype(string wt)
    {
        wp_terraintype = wt;
    }

    int return_terrain_cost()
    {
        if (wp_terraintype == "LAND")
        {
            terrainCost = 1;
            return 1;
        }
        if (wp_terraintype == "WATER")
        {
            terrainCost = 4;
            return 4;
        }
        if (wp_terraintype == "MOUNTAIN")
        {
            terrainCost = 6;
            return 6;
        }
        if (wp_terraintype == "NULL")
        {
            terrainCost = 999;
            return 999;
        }
        if (wp_terraintype == "NUKE")
        {
            terrainCost = 0;
            return 0;
        }
        if (wp_terraintype == "AIR")
        {
            terrainCost = 0;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    void resetall()
    {
         pos_x = 0; // position in grid
         pos_y = 0;
         x = 0;
         y = 0;
         z = 0;

         terrainCost = 0; // this cost is determined by terrain type, which is used in the A* pathfinding
         f_cost = 0;

         influence = 0;
         current_owner = "NULL";
         waypointname = "WP";
         wp_terraintype = "NULL";
    }

    void CWaypointSetup(float _x, float _y, float _z)
    {
        x = _x; y = _y; z = _z;
    }
};
```

Comment: Please visit [this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to try and have both of your accounts merged; this will allow you to edit the post, comment and accept an answer should you receive one that help you solve your issue.

Comment: You do realize Wikipedia has very simple pseudo code for the A* algorithm. Just copy that

Answer (score 2):

Several issues with your code.

1. The code is executed top to bottom in several places there are bits of code that that just don't make sense.

   In the for_each function there are a few ifs that test on a `check` variable and immediately continue, When that happens they variable isn't reset.

   At the start of the pathfinder while loop you first copy the front of the open set and then sort and pop_front it. Instead you will want to sort then copy the front and after that pop_front.
2. You never add the destination to the open set at all **so it can never be selected from it**.
3. You used `using namespace std;` at some point, that's a bad habit to get into as it paves the way to name conflicts down the line.
4. Your code leaks like a sieve, you don't `delete` anything you have `new`ed.

   In fact you don't need to allocate any new CWaypoints during pathfinding at all.